# How to simply achieve Google Logout kind of "click anywhere to close" kind of functionality?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, user-interface

Here is what my team member was looking for: How to provide a functionality like GMail where you click on your email and it opens up Logout div with some additional user information and when you click anywhere outside of document it closes that box (hides the div)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It can be achieved using following code:

HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="show-card">Dharmavir</a>
<div id="user-card" style="display:none">
    <p>
        Welcome Dharmavir,<br />
        ABC Software, Inc
    </p>
    <a href="#">Logout</a>
<div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // To show user-box
    $("#show-card").mouseup(function(){
        $("#user-card").show();

        // To hide user-box
        $(document).mousedown(function(){
            $("#user-card").hide();
            $(this).unbind("mousedown");
        })
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
#user-card {
    height:75px;
    width:200px;
    border:solid 1px #ccc;
}
```

JSFiddle for the same can be seen at http://jsfiddle.net/dharmavir/tPdsE/

Comment: Binding an event inside an event handler is usually a really bad idea.

Comment: @ThiefMaster Thank you for bringing that to my notice, I really missed that out as I lost my earlier fiddle in hurry. I have corrected code here as well as on fiddle. You can check that. I didn't wanted to bind an event insider another. They were just side by side but it was just went unnoticed as it worked.

Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve this is binding a `click` handler for the whole `document` which closes the box and also one for the box. In the box's event you stop the propagation of the click event so:

```
$(document).on('click', function() {
    $('#box').hide();
});

$('#box').on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThiefMaster/JTtXB/
Note that you also need to stop the propagation of whatever click event opens the box or it will be closed again immediately.

Comment: I understand that and that's why I have used MouseUp and MouseDown event so that I don't need to use stop propogation.

Another problem with above approach is $('#box').hide(); will be called every time you click anywhere in your document. So you must unbind that if you want to stop that.

I have updated your fiddle to show what I am trying to tell you: http://jsfiddle.net/dharmavir/JTtXB/1/

With fiddle that I have created you won't find that problem. Let me know if we can come up with better approach than both of us have so far.

Comment: No need to unbind it - if the box is invisible it doesn't do anything.

Comment: I know it won't do anything but than why to have that line execute at every click on the document?

Comment: Is that a problem, the only time you click is when you are leaving the page, or using a form.